# Get last string element in DataFrame column conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Suppose I have the following simple dataframe:

```
df_data=pd.DataFrame({'name':['ABC','ABC XYZ']})
```

To get the last element I apply:

```
df_end= pd.DataFrame(df_data.name.str.split().str.get(-1), columns=['name'])
```

The result is `ABC`. I'd like to get None when the length of `name` is less than 2. I have tried the following, but I am not getting right:

```
df_end['name'] = df_data.name.str.split().apply(lambda x: x[-1] if len(x)>1)
```

I should not get `ABC` as the last element for `ABC`, but I should get `XYZ` in `ABC XYZ`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try:

```
df_data['name'].str.extract('\s(\S+)$')
```

Output:

```
     0
0  NaN
1  XYZ
```

Comment: why  `df_end= pd.DataFrame(df_data.name.str.extract('\s(\S+)$'),columns=['name'])` does not give the last string with the same data? Getting NaN for the two rows.

Comment: Because the series `df_data.name.str.extract('\s(\S+)$')` has `0` as names. You can do: `pd.DataFrame(df_data['name'].str.extract('\s(\S+)$').values,columns=['name'])`

Answer (score 1):

If you expect many splits, it can be faster to `rpartition` as you want only the last. Then mask any single word strings.

```
u = df_data.name.str.rpartition()
u[2].where(u[0].ne(''))

#0    NaN
#1    XYZ
#Name: 2, dtype: object
```